# How do I fix this 'phishing' warning in my app deployed in vercel?

Tags: node.js, heroku, crud, vercel, phishing

Hi people: I deployed my videogames CRUD in heroku + vercel and I'm getting a "phishing warning" like this one from every browser when I visit the site:

[image]

I tried redeploying the app with a different name but I keep getting this error as others do when they visit it.

This is my site: https://pi-videogames-nk.vercel.app/

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a warning triggered because your site has ended up in one of the Safe Browsing lists.

You can report the mistake here: https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpi-videogames-nk.vercel.app%2F

As for how it ended up be flagged... Could just be a false positive detection. As well as manual reports of malicious content, Google do some level of automated scanning.